# Move GWT Logging window

Tags: java, gwt, logging

I am currently using GWT's built in logger, however the way it is attached to the RootPanel is awkward, and it is usually obscured by any panels placed on top. Does anybody know how to move it? I never attached it to the main panel, it seems like it attaches itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging#Different_Types_of_Handlers

> Although the PopupLogHandler is easy to use, it is also a bit invasive. A better solution for most apps is to disable the PopupLogHandler and instead send the log messages to a Panel somewhere in your app.

Just use

```
logger.addHandler(new HasWidgetsLogHandler(customLogArea));
```

where customLogArea can be anything that implements [HasWidgets](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasWidgets.html) (e.g. a FlowPanel, a RootPanel, ...). This allows you to create the log area in your HTML page, in your code or in uiBinder. Also, you can style it any way you like (using CSS or code).

Answer (score 10):

Are you refering to the popup panel?
If you are developing on Firefox or Chrome, try using the firebug/developer console instead.
I use the following configuration.

```
<set-property name='gwt.logging.enabled' value='TRUE'/>           
<set-property name='gwt.logging.consoleHandler' value='ENABLED'/>
<set-property name='gwt.logging.firebugHandler' value='ENABLED'/>  
<set-property name='gwt.logging.popupHandler' value='DISABLED'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing the panel by adding the following to the gwt.xml file:

```
`<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="DISABLED" />`
```